# Adding text before each line in file in linux

Tags: linux, loops, for-loop, awk

Text file has sample.txt

```
a/b/1
b/f/2
y/z/3
a/y/4
t/q/5
```

want an output like

```
a/1
a/2
a/3
a/4
a/5
```

tried code

```
dir="a/"
num=$(wc -l < sample.txt)
 for ((i=1; i<=$num; i++));
 do
 echo "$dir""`awk -F "/" '{print $NF}' sample.txt`"
 echo "$i"
 break
 done
```

but this gives me output

```
a/1
2
3
4
5
```

Issue is using awk it is updating only the first row. Please help

Comment: Do you want to use the `a/` because that's what the first line starts with, or is it just a coincidence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -F'/' '{print "a/"$3}' Sample.txt
```

(or)

```
awk -F'/' '{print "a/"$NF}' Sample.txt
```

Comment: Instead of just dumping a script providing a possible answer, you might want to elaborate on it a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

A simple while loop with `IFS` set to include `'/'` works just as well, e.g.

```
while IFS="$IFS/" read -r a b c; do 
    [ -z "$pfx" ] && pfx=$a          ## if prefix not set, set it with 1st read
    echo "$pfx/$c"
done <tripfile.txt
```

**Example Input**

```
$ cat tripfile.txt
a/b/1
b/f/2
y/z/3
a/y/4
t/q/5
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ while IFS="$IFS/" read -r a b c; do [ -z "$pfx" ] && pfx=$a; \
echo "$pfx/$c"; done <tripfile.txt)
a/1
a/2
a/3
a/4
a/5
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a text processing tool such as awk to do this without a shell loop:

```
awk -F/ '{ print "a" FS $NF }' file
```

Set the field separator to `/`, then print the leading text ("a" in this example), followed by the field separator, followed by the last field.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F/ 'NR==1{x=$1} {print x"/"$3}' sample.txt
a/1
a/2
a/3
a/4
a/5
```

#### How it works

- `-F/`

  This sets the field separator to `/`.
- `NR==1{x=$1}`

  This saves the first field of the first line in variable `x`.
- `print x"/"$3`

  This prints the variable `x`, followed by a slash, followed by the third field of the current line.